# modular logs (index arithmetic) to find remainder

Tags: modular-arithmetic

use the index arithmetic to find the remainder when $46^{88}$ times $5^{400}$ is divided by $29$.

I have solved this using typical modulo operations

first by reducing $46$ to $17$ then finding the order of $17$ and dividing $88$ by the order. which in this case is $4$ so it leaves me with $1$ times $5^{400}$ (mod $29$)

I then find the order of $5$ (mod $29$) which is $14$ and leaves me with

1 times $5^8$ (mod $29$). So i get the answer of $3$(mod $29$)

BUT my professor wants me to use the index arithmetic notation and I am confused on how to go through these steps using that notation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is "index arithmetic" ?

Comment: http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/385

Answer (score 1):

So I first find a primitive root of $29$ which I used $3$.
Let $\phi$ = Euler function$(n)$.

$$3^{x} \equiv a \mod{29} \equiv ( \text{ ind$3(a)$ = $x$ })$$
$$\text{ind}3(46^{88} \cdot 5^{400})  (\text{ mod }\phi(29))$$
$$\text{ind}3(46^{88}) + \text{ind}3(5^{400})  (\text{mod} \phi(29))$$
$$88(\text{ind}3(46)) + 400(\text{ind}3(5))  (\text{mod} \phi(29))$$
$$4(\text{ind}3(17)) + 8(\text{ind}3(5))  (\text{mod} \phi(29))$$
$$4(21) + 8 (10)   (\text{mod} \phi(29))$$
$$0 + 24   (\text{mod} \phi(29))$$
and finally $24 \mod{29}$ is the remainder.